# Possible to automate a web search?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping

Is it possible in a website search form to enter in series of searches?  I have a list of destinations and would like to see if for each destination the search returns a result or throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into [Watir](http://watir.com/) - it allows automating the browser(possibly only IE, not sure)  and is **the** tool to use for what you've described. You can go to a specified site, refer to HTML elements on the page and set their values (click buttons, fill search forms, etc).

It's also been ported into several other languages, such as #C (WatiN) and Java (WatiJ) and probably more.

Answer (score 1):

My tool of choice for a problem like this would be to use [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) in combination with [Capybara](http://github.com/jnicklas/capybara).

Cucumber is a nice DSL for writing out tasks such as these, although isn't strictly necessary for your problem.

Capybara is a browser simulator/driver wrapper for automated interaction with a website.

Both are well documented.